# Conditional getter in nHibernate class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, getter

Can i have a conditional getter like this:

Where i need to check if a property is null, if its null return another property of the same class.

*This is a class for nHibernate mapping.*

```
public virtual District District 
        {
            get 
            {
                return this.District == null ? this.Zone : this.District; 
            } 
            set
            {
                this.District = value;
            }
        }
```

When i tried this the server just hangs up...

Answer (score 4):

You've defined your property recursively (both the getter and the setter actually call themselves). You'd need to use a internal field to store the actual value:

```
private District district;

public virtual District District 
{
    get 
    {
        return this.district ?? this.Zone; 
    } 
    set
    {
        this.district = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK i understand...but this will affect in some way nHibernate mappings?

Comment: @aGuy I'm not that familiar with nHibernate, but I'm fairly certain you can create a mapping to the field rather than the property.

Comment: Original example throws stackoverflow exception when getter or setter are invoked

Answer (score 2):

In the case of NHibernate Mapping, I wouldn't add any logic to a mapped property. In that case, I would add a distinct method:

```
public virtual District District  { get; set; }

public virtual District GetDistrictOrDefault()
{
    return District ?? this.Zone;
}
```

Or you might want to protect the mapped District-Property - you could provide a second one wrapping the protected property providing some logic:

```
// Mapped with NHibernate
protected virtual District District  { get; set; }

public virtual District DistrictOrDefault // You might find a better naming... 
{
    get 
    {
        return District ?? this.Zone; 
    } 
    set
    {
        District = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and quite simple to do just that. NHibernate allows us to specify access strategy for individual property. I'm frequently use something like this:

```
protected District _district;
public virtual District District 
{
    get { return _district ?? this.Zone; }
    set { _district = value; }
}
```

And mapping for the property:

```
<property name="District" access="field.camelcase-underscore" />
```

In this mapping scheme, your code will use the property to get/set data, while NHibernate uses the field to do the same. If you leave out the access setting, in case the property District is really NULL, NHibernate will think that you have changed the property District to the new value and it will try to update the corresponding database record. This might result in bugs.
I've never used Fluent NHibernate, so I don't know how to do that with Fluent.